# JSF populating a Datatable via a List

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to populate a dataTable via a list. Essentially my app, submits a search parameter and I can access the search results like so:

```
resultsToRender = resultsBean.getResults();
```

And then I am creating my list like so:

```
setSearchItems(new ArrayList<SelectItem>());    
for( Result result : resultsBean.getResults() )
           {                               
               String item= result.getEntity().get( "content.item-name" );

               searchItems.add(new searchItems(item));
           }
```

Whilst my data table seems to pick up the correct number of rows according to the search parameters I am not entirely sure how to setup my list so that I can displays the row specific data, at the moment every row in my dataTable simply displays the information of the last item in my list.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *at the moment every row in my dataTable simply displays the information of the last item in my list.*

That can happen when either the `entity` property of `result` is `static`, or that `searchItems` constructor assigns the `item` to a static property.

Those properties should not be `static`. Remove that modifier.

Comment: My problem is that I dont know how to provide an explicitly reference for each row. Using the above example I use this to set the table data: "h:dataTable var="searchItems" value="#{searchBean.searchItems}" but I cannot get my IDE to recognise: <h:outputText value="#{searchItems.item}" /> I get a property error. I am obviously not setting up my list properly or referencing it wrong. Is there a resource somewhere that shows how to populate a list via a list? Thx for the help!

Comment: Git it working via your excellent blog, for anyone whose interested: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html